# Selenium Chrome certificate selection in popup use C#

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I suppress or automatically dismiss the client certificate selection dialog with selenium (chrome driver)?

#### Question

I have specific certificate.

[image: My Certificates]

Answer (score 0):

Well, short version: you can't...

Long version?

Here we go:

Every browser has one of two options: or has his own "certificate database" or are using the system certificate database. So you cannot select the certificate in the window, but you can force (more likely erase) the certificate database to only find one certificate.

But how that information helps you? well, the chrome driver, and I imagine the rest too, if only have one certificate, you can tell the browser that  for specific domain do the certificate login automatically with a value: AutoSelectCertificateForUrls, So, here goes the bum:

In linux (for every platform the process is different from here, so I'll explain linux, if you need other, do some research) may exists or you can create a file in one or both of this paths:
/home/your-user/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/auto_select_certificate.json
and this other one:
/home/your-user/etc/opt/auto_select_certificate.json
in both you need to put the same content:
{"AutoSelectCertificateForUrls":["{"pattern":"[*.]domain.us","filter":{}}"]}
that content tells the chrome driver: "if you see the a domain like this: '"[*.]domain.us"' and it ask for certificate, please send the "only" certificate I have...

so at this point you only need to remove all certificates and add the one you need.

To manage the certificates linux, you need to edit the content of your user's certificate database located "usually" here:

/home/your-user/.pki/nssdb

It's up to you to add there your certificate, remember has to be only ONE.

after that if you use selenium and load the url that usually shows the certificate selection modal, it will be not shown and will automatically authenticate with your certificate.